# Input Redirection not working?

Tags: c

My instructions: Write a program that repeatedly (until end-of-file) reads in a character
from the input stream. If the character is upper case, change it to lower case
and write it to the output stream. For all other characters, write the
character unchanged to the output stream.
Use getchar() for input, Use putchar() for output, and use input redirection
for connecting the input file to the program

My project name is Input and my textfile is input.txt.  When I run it I type "Input < input.txt"  The program just mimics that on the command window though so how do I get it to read from the text file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  char c, x;


   c=getchar();

  while (c != EOF)
 {

    c=getchar();
     x = tolower(c);
     if (isupper(c))
    {
        putchar(x);

    }
    else 
    {
        putchar(c);

    }

 }
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I believe that your problem is that you don't want to open the program up and then type in `Input < input.txt`.  You need to execute that command from the command-line.

Comment: Did you include the quotes around the command? If so, remove them. If not, maybe Win8 already has a command called `Input`. Try compiling your code to an exe with a different name.

Comment: For future reference, please copy and paste the exact command you typed and the output it produced.

Comment: Note that your code skips the first character.  You should also read values from `getchar()` into an `int` so that EOF is recognized properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you do not want to go to the program and type in `Input < input.txt`.  Instead, you want to open a terminal program, change directory into the directory containing the project, and then run the program from the command line by writing `Input < input.txt`.  This starts up the program and uses the contents of `input.txt` as the standard input stream, rather than reading text from the console.

That said, there are two bugs in your code.  First, note that you have the line

```
c = getchar();
```

outside of your loop that does the input reading.  You then immediately call

```
c = getchar();
```

again inside the loop.  This means that you are discarding the very first character that you read in.

Second, your loop runs one more time than it needs to.  If the second call to `getchar()` returns `EOF`, you do not detect this until after the current loop iteration finishes.  This is because your check for `EOF` is at the top of the loop, which isn't reached until after you've already printed out the `EOF` character.  To fix this, consider using the loop-and-a-half idiom and breaking out of the loop in the middle:

```
for (;;) {
    /* Read data. */
    if (/* no data left */) break;

    /* Process data. */
}
```

Stylistically, are you sure that you need both the `if` and `else` branches here?  Recall that `tolower` will not change the values of characters that aren't upper-case, so having one case for upper-case letters and one for lower-case is redundant.  You can just output the character produced by `tolower` without the special cases.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way of doing this *for ASCII text only* is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(tolower(c));

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

As textbooks are so fond of saying, *UTF-8 is left as an easy exercise to the reader* ;-)